# Different versions of IIS on Different Windows versions?

Tags: iis

On Win XP I installed IIS from ControlPanel,... and it's version is 5.1
So my question is what does this version mean? Does it go to 6.0 for example with Windows Vista OR is it related to the version of .NET Framework and ASP.net that I install? and as default does an IIS 6.0 version mean it is a Win Vista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my knowledge each Windows version comes with an included IIS version which you're generally stuck with (possible updates may come down from Windows Update, but I wouldn't expect any in general).

So from my experience whichever version of IIS you get when you install the component is the one you're stuck with - ie. you can't upgrade to IIS 6 if you're using Windows XP. I'm using Windows XP and I'm stuck with v5.1 also. (It's not related to your .NET version).

As for which versions of IIS for which Windows version, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#Versions

Comment: This is simply wrong. You're referring to the free version that comes with some Windows version as part of the installable Windows components. The commercial (paid) version of IIS can be upgraded from any version to any other version that is compatible with the OS you want to install it on (IOW, if you have IIS 5.x installed on XP, and there's a version of IIS 6 that's compatible with XP, you can upgrade to IIS 6 if you want to buy the upgraded version). Also, the IIS version has no connection to the OS version at all; it just happens to coincide on the original WinXP installation.

Comment: For instance, on Win7 Professional 64-bit, the included version of IIS is 7 and the OS version is 6.1.

Comment: I only responded with the best of my knowledge. I wasn't even aware Microsoft produced a separate version of IIS, let alone a paid version (apart from the cost of Windows itself). Where do you get the paid IIS version, depending on cost I may be interested in upgrading.

Comment: It's now been merged into part of the Windows Server architecture, so you have to buy the Server OS. (It used to be a separate product; it appears that now it's part of the server OS; for instance, Windows Server 2008 includes IIS 7.5.) I'll retract my downvote (although I probably shouldn't, because you're still wrong about it being connected to the Windows OS version number - you might want to edit that part out). :)

Comment: @ken White - You are pretty much wrong with everything you say here, while devlop is pretty much correct. Every version of IIS from 1.0 was either free or came with the OS. You could never buy a version of IIS separately. Except for NT4 which could run IIS 2,3 or 4 there was only a single version of IIS for each OS Version. The version numbers do not always match but that doesn't make any difference. Win7 has IIS 7.5 not 7.